# How to get hold of the currently running instance of IE

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript

Using *VBScript* to open IE and navigate a particular URL can be done by:

```
Dim ie

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Navigate "about:blank"
ie.Visible = True
```

Is there a way to get the currently running instance of IE instead of creating a new one?

```
Set ie = GetObject(, "InternetExplorer.Application")
```

I can't get the above code to work; what am I missing?

If yes, is it possible to programmatically display currently open tabs simultaneously?
Suppose current instance of IE have 2 tabs open, when I get hold of the instance, it displays tab 1.
After a few minutes, switch display to tab 2. Is this possible using VBScript?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Thanks. I guess my key words were lousy to have missed that. Btw, while your at it, is my second question possible too?

Comment: See the comments to my answer there. The loop iterates over all IE instances in the order they were spawned. Each tab counts as a separate instance.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Ah. So each tab is a different instance. I thought just one with a collection of all tab objects. I'll try something out, not really well versed in VBscript, too basic. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set AllWindows = objShell.Windows
For Each window in AllWindows
    msgbox window.locationname & " " & window.documents(0).body.innertext
Next
```

For historical reasons this lists explorer and internet explorer windows. The window object in my code is an IE object (or a folder object).

From IE 4 to 6, 7, or 8 (I don't remember) Explorer did folders and web sites. Internet Explorer just hosted explorer. This was changed for security reasons to individual programs. If I talk about the desktop ... and the hosting, ok I will. In IE 4, There is the Windows Desktop (has windows and minimised programs appear as icons or titlebars), then there is Explorer's desktop, this hosts an internet explorer desktop, which hosts web pages (active desktop item) and the explorer's desktop with icons.

Comment: In your window loop, you can add this line to filter out the explorer windows. `If InStr(1, window.FullName, "iexplore.exe", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then`